# Feature flags azure with vue.js (javascript)

Tags: javascript, azure, api, vue.js, frontend

I want to create and build a Vue.js app that uses feature flags (Azure Portal).
The app will be a feature manager and the backend will be azure.

Where can I find help and guidance on how to get and add features of azure in my app?

The app should display all the features and which feature on or off, with a options to change features and add.

Do I have a tutorial or APIs that I can use? I would appreciate your assistance.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this belongs on https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta as a discussion

Comment: someone help?  please

Answer (score 1):

## You can use restapi to do that.

**Related Post:**

[How to use Azure App Configuration REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61899063/how-to-use-azure-app-configuration-rest-api)

*I can show you how can I find it. Usually, When I want the same function as on azure portal, I like to use F12 to find out what api is used for this request, and then go to Google search.*

[image]